# Deciding to make it a root of aggregate or to keep it as member of aggregate root.

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I remember in Eric Evans book on DDD, if an entity can only be understood in term of other entity (the root of aggregate), then make it a "plain" entity (member of AR).

My question: what exactly "can be understood on its own" means? What questions should I be asking myself to know if an entity can be understood on its own or not?

Comment: If it can can be created on its own or it must be created in the context of another. Or, if ALL the invariants hold if you directly modify that entity.

Comment: Hi Constantin, can you put your comment in the answer section please, so I can upvote it?

Oh and another related question: can an operation in an AR causes creation of an instance of another AR (different type)?

Comment: Maybe this should help answering my second question: http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/

Answer (score 0):

> My question: what exactly "can be understood on its own" means?

If it can can be created on its own or it *must* be created in the context of another.

> What questions should I be asking myself to know if an entity can be understood on its own or not?

"Do **all** the business invariants hold if I directly modify that entity or, in fact, I need to do a check (i.e. `if` statement) on a computation on a collection of other *related* entities to ensure that a particular *business rule* is verified?"

Another question is: "Do I have all the information in this entity to verify **all** the business rules?"

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class that has no reason to exist other than to be *part of* another then it is *not* an AR.  The archetypal example is `Order` and `Orderitem`.  You never want to keep track of the life cycle an `OrderItem`.  In fact, you probably would want to model the `OrderItem` as a value object.  Not all of these concepts in your domain are necessarily going to be that apparent though.

As for [Udi's post](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/) that you linked to: being able to create an AR from another would depend on that AR being part of your Bounded Context.  Also, I nowadays prefer returning events from my domain rather than raising them from within the domain.